# Issue regarding subreprt in active report 7

Tags: activereports

I want display records in the active reports 7 as 4 record in one page  and information that record in the next page?So,I what should use do that?I have tried sub-report and page break but that doesn't work?
Is there any other way to use sub report or any other thing that we can use.

Answer (score 2):

As far my understanding of the issue goes, you want to show 4 records on a page and then show the remaining data on the new page. There isn't any direct way to achieve this.

However a workaround for you is to make use of the If-else loop in the Detail's Format event. Add a counter in the Detail's Format event and when it reaches '4', set the NewPage property of Detail Section to 'After' under the 'If' condition and under the 'Else' part reset the NewPage property of Detail Section to 'None'.

Please share your observations with us.

Regards,
Mohita